# Como fixar o tamanho do ícone de uma ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou usando uma ExpandableListView, onde tenho um ícone de expansão de conteúdo, mas toda vez aumento a altura da opção, a imagem fica com a mesma altura, distorcendo a imagem. Como faço para fixar o tamanho?

Na classe eu faço a seguinte chamada ao xml:

> expandableListView.setGroupIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_group));

XML:

[image: xml icon_group]

Resultado final:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia postar o xml do layout desse item?

Comment: Inseri o xml na pergunta, Wakim.

Comment: Então... Nunca usei o `ExpandableListView` em minúcias, mas a grande maioria dos problemas com essa distorção se resolve usando um `9-patch` ao invés de um asset simples. Basicamente seria criar um `9-patch` desse ícone com cada ponta tendo 1 pixel transparente para redimensionar, assim da pra manter a parte opaca do ícone intacta. Pra gerar o 9-patch, recomendo esse site: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html